# How to use variables from one function in another?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to use the "costOfCar" function in the "InterestPaid" function. I would appreciate any help.

```
namespace Functions9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Double userCarCost, userDownPayment, userInterestRatePercentage, test; //declares "userCarCost" , "userDownPayment variable", "userInterestRatePercentage"
            Console.WriteLine("This program will do some calculations for you about a car loan."); //explains the purpose and function of program to user
            Console.WriteLine(); //adds an empty line
            Console.WriteLine("What is the cost of your new car?"); //prompt user for input
            userCarCost = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); //converts user input regarding car cost to double and stores in "userCarCost" variable
            Console.WriteLine(); //adds an empty line
            Console.WriteLine("How much money will you put as a down payment");
            userDownPayment = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); //converts user input regarding down payment to double and stores in "userDownPayment" variable
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your interest rate percentage? Put a point before the number");
            userInterestRatePercentage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); //converts user input regarding interest rate to double and stores in "userInterestRatePercentage" variable
            Console.WriteLine(); //adds an empty line
            Console.WriteLine("How many years before you pay back the loan?");

            CostOfCar(userCarCost, userDownPayment);
        }
        static double CostOfCar(double number1, double number2)
        {

            double costOfCar = number1 - number2; //"costOfCar" variable is determined by subtracting "userCarCost", "userDownPayment"
            return costOfCar; // returns the cost of the car to the main method
        }

        static double InterestPaid(double number1, double number2)
        {
            double interestPaid = number1 * number2;
            return interestPaid;


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem calling the method? If so, please show what errors you're getting.

Comment: use the return value of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Just call it?

```
    static double InterestPaid (double number1, double number2)
    {
        double interestPaid = number1 * number2 * CostOfCar(number1, number2);
        return interestPaid;
    }
```

Or with the correct formula you need.

(update according remark):

```
    static double InterestPaid (double number1, double number2)
    {
        var costOfCar = CostOfCar(number1, number);
        double interestPaid = number1 * number2 * costOfCar;
        return interestPaid;
    }
```

Btw, it is better to name functions with a verb, like CalculateCostOfCar.

Comment: Calling it does not capture the returned value - unless the function is called correctly. The calling class must set up a variable to which the computed value is returned.

Comment: I cannot see it in the original answer, but I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yeah, I see what you are saying. Look at OP call to `CostOfCar()`, though. I cleaned up the question a bit. It looks like the OP also doesn't understand how to capture values returned by a function, e.g. `double cost = functionCall()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need something to capture the value.

In `Main`, instead of

```
CostOfCar(userCarCost, userDownPayment);
```

write

```
double cost = CostOfCar(userCarCost, userDownPayment);
```

Here, the variable `cost` is capturing the returned value from the function for later use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static double InterestPaid (double number1, double number2)
    {            
        var val=Program.CostOfCar(number1, number2);
        double interestPaid = number1 * number2;
        var total=val+interestpaid;
        return total;
    }
```